# Не работает android-парсер html страниц

Tags: java, android, android-studio, парсер, jsoup

Здравствуйте. Я переписал парсер из одного видеоурока(НЕ РЕКЛАМА): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQ7oWE0yJkE . Вроде делал всё точь-в-точь как на видео, но он не работает. Просто выводит белый экран, и всё? В чем может быть проблема? Код прилагаю:

MainActivity

```
package com.example.max.webpageparser;                                                              

import android.app.Activity;                                                                        
import android.os.AsyncTask;                                                                        
import android.os.Bundle;                                                                           
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;                                                                 
import android.widget.ListView;                                                                     

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;                                                                             
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;                                                                    
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;                                                                     
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;                                                                   

import java.io.IOException;                                                                         
import java.util.ArrayList;                                                                         

public class MainActivity extends Activity {                                                        

public Elements content;                                                                        
public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();                                         
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;                                                           
private ListView lv;                                                                            

@Override                                                                                       
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                            
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                         
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                                                     

    lv=findViewById(R.id.listView1);                                                            
    new NewThread().execute();                                                                  
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.pro_item, titleList);           
}                                                                                               

public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{                                 

    @Override                                                                                   
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {                                            
        Document doc;                                                                           

        try{                                                                                    
            doc= Jsoup.connect("https://www.volzsky.ru/index.php?wx=16").get();                 
            content = doc.select(".btc_p");                                                     
            titleList.clear();                                                                  
            for(Element contents: content){                                                     
                titleList.add(contents.text());                                                 
            }                                                                                   
        }catch (IOException e){                                                                 
            e.printStackTrace();                                                                
        }                                                                                       

        return null;                                                                            
    }                                                                                           


    @Override                                                                                   
    protected void onPreExecute() {                                                             

         lv.setAdapter(adapter);                                                                
    }                                                                                           



}
```

}

main_activity.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pro_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` и `main_activity.xml` - в проекте у Вас так же?

Comment: Нет, в проекте с этим всё в норме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Адаптер не может сам догадаться, что содержимое списка изменилось, поэтому после добавления в список нужно уведомить его вызовом `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Так как это метод, изменяющий UI и его нужно вызывать в основном потоке, то лучше добавить в `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`

```
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    //..................

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //..................

}
```